# How useful is program search in the field of programming-language theory?

Tags: pl.programming-languages, computability, machine-learning, genetic-programming

I've been thinking: computing systems such as the Lambda Calculus and its variations are usually very simple and can be implemented in as few as ~80 lines of Haskell code. There is a [self-interpreter for the Binary Lambda Calculus in 210 bits](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~tromp/cl/cl.html).

Considering PL research mostly consists of the search of similar systems with desirable characteristics (such as being supercompilable, or capable of expressing proofs), and taking in account how information-starved those systems are, wouldn't it be interesting to use automated search techniques such as genetic programming or just breadth-first search to find those?

Has that been tried already?

Comment: Given that Tromp's inefficient self-interpreter already takes 210 bits (i.e. lives in a naive search space of size $2^{210}$), how likely is it that interesting programs can be found by brute force search such as generic algorithms? For example supercompilation techniques today only work on extremely short programs (e.g. < 10 commands).

Comment: The question is, what is the specification of the program you are looking for? If you have an equational description, then higher-order unification is your friend. In more generality, you might be interested in [program synthesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_synthesis).